# Rails 3 - Can I get a list of all the view files (partials included) that are being rendered on a given page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is this possible? I was asked to generate a list of the views being rendered in our admin portal that can then be added to a layout file. Hope that makes sense.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I follow but since the clock is ticking and no one has weighed in, I'll bite... wouldn't this be in your log?  If you are logging at the debug level, you should see a line for each view or partial rendered.

Comment: Right, after the fact. Sorry I wasn't clearer on this. I'm looking for some way to print out on the page something like:

This page includes the following views: 

`app/views/something/index.html.erb`
`layout/admin.html.erb`
`layout/user.html.erb` etc... or if the filename can't be given, some sort of reference to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use gem 'rails-footnotes', this is show all partials, action, variables, and other things in given page.